# Why do some type 1 conditional sentences use "can" instead of "will be able to"?

Tags: verbs, usage

I've always thought that when using a type 1 conditional, we should always use "will/won't be able to" instead of "can/can't", but then I come up with some contexts where "can/can't" seems to be fine too. I don't know why. Can somebody explain?

Context 1

A: The bus station will be closed by 19:00. Will you need a ride?

B: It's okay. There's another station down the street. **If it stays open, I can still take a bus tomorrow.**

Context 2

A: I really want to repair our roof, but it will cost about 3,000 dollars.

B: I have already applied for the compensation, but the approval process is going to take at least 30 days. **If we receive more than 3,000 dollars, we can use the money to repair the roof next month.**

Context 3

A: Do you know where to buy some apples?

B: Why?

A: They have some of the best apples in the world here, and we are leaving early tomorrow morning. **If I don't buy some tonight, I can't make some delicious apple juice for my parent tomorrow.**

PS: I think maybe contexts 1 and 2 are more suitable for "can", while context 3 is a little disputable. If someone can explain this, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: A lot of more complex so-called tenses in English, native speakers often don't use when the temporal relationships are clear without. There is no "future tense" in English -  the simple present, the modal "will" and the complex "be going to" are all ways in which we sometimes express future meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, in (1) and (2), the speaker is imagining themself in the hypothetical situation and therefore thinking of the possibility in the present tense.

"The bus station is still open, so I can take a bus." (Why would there be two bus stations in the same street?)

"We have received more than $3000, so we can repair the roof."

(3) is a negative sentence, so I don't find *can't* so natural.

"If I don't buy apples tonight, I won't be able to make any apple juice tomorrow."

Comment: For some reason, "can't" seems to be less acceptable in future tense.

Comment: Acceptable to whom? You were told in response to your original question on ELU that 'can't' is often used when speaking about the near future.

Comment: That’s not the point. The point is that the negative form is less acceptable than “can” when referring to the future.

Comment: @Skywarrior - it is equally 'acceptable'. Kate is right. If you crash your car today, you can't drive it to the beach tomorrow. If you marry Jane today, you can't date Mary next week.

Comment: A native speaker told me this is not acceptable: A Hey, remember to show up at the bus station on time. We will go for a pre-drink at Judy’s first. B: I forgot to tell you. I have to stay at home and study. My mom wants me to spend more time studying than going out. A: Damn that sucks. **If you don’t come with us, you can’t hang out with some really cool people tomorrow night.**

Comment: Some people say I can use can’t while others say I should use won’t be able to only. I am really confused now.

Comment: @Skywarrior - Don't be confused. **Two** experienced educated native speakers with high reputation on this site have told you that you can use 'can't' about the future. The 'native speaker' who told you otherwise is mistaken. Why ask here if you don't like the answers?

Comment: Just to make sure. So you mean this is acceptable as well? **If you don’t come with us, you can’t hang out with some really cool people tomorrow**

Comment: Another one that many native speaks say is wrong is this: He’s very experienced, but he doesn’t like speaking to strangers. **If you don’t ask him nicely, you can’t get any useful information from him tomorrow.**

Comment: @Skywarrior - both are fine.

Comment: Cool thanks for your reply

Comment: It's true that I said that I found 'won't be able to' more idiomatic in your 'apple juice' example. **If you don’t ask him nicely, you can’t get any useful information from him** describes a general truth, but if you add **tomorrow** to make it a prediction, I think **won't be able to** sounds better - but there isn't a hard and fast rule.

Comment: So the original one “If you don’t ask him nicely, you can’t get any useful information from him tomorrow” is still acceptable but not very idiomatic?

Comment: It sounds awkward to me because, until you hear 'tomorrow', it seems to be a description of how he usually is.

Comment: I think there are some nuances:

“If I don’t do further research tonight, I can’t publish my paper next week.” sounds okay. Without including further research results, it’s still possible for me to publish my paper, but in that case my paper might not be academically important, which is not the goal I I want to achieve.

”If I don’t provide my draft tonight, I can’t publish my paper next week.”sounds quite weird. Without providing the draft, which is a necessary process of publishing something, I won’t be able to do the act of publishing.

I hope you understand what I mean here

Answer (score 0):

***"I can't make some delicious apple juice"***:-

*This is a direct sentence suggesting a straightforward consequence by implying limitation in your ability to do that thing(to make some delicious apple juice) if you don't do the 1st thing(buying of some delicious apples).*

***"I will not be able to make some delicious apple juice"***-

*This is a bit more formal sentence highlighting the future consequence by implying explicitly the inability to that thing (to make some delicious apple juice)suggesting a sense of planning.*

Comment: That's quite a good explanation. I will say that the first one implies the lack of opportunity while the other is the lack of ability. 

What do you think about the "can" examples in context 1&2?

Answer (score 0):

First, this isn't particular to first conditionals -- this is just about "can".

One function of "can" is to indicate *the ability to do something in the future*. It also strongly implies that that's what will happen.

Your first two sentences can be rewritten like this:

> If it stays open, I **will have the ability to** take a bus tomorrow (so that will be my plan).
>
> If we receive more than 3,000 dollars, we **will have the ability to** use the money to repair the roof next month (and we should do that).

Your third sentence isn't correct though. This function of "can" always indicates an ability. Even if you negate the phrase, you don't negate the ability, you only negate the action itself, indicating *the ability to **not** do something*. It cannot indicate the ***inability** to do something*.

So if we take your third sentence, and use "can" and "not" instead of "can't", we get this:

> If I don't buy some tonight, I can [not make some delicious apple juice for my parent] tomorrow.

This means "*I will have the ability to not make apple juice*", which means "not making apple juice" is an option, but I could also choose to make it.

Comment: can and am able. can and will be able. I will be able to take the bus.